# How can I read text from a textfile displayed in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a webpage with an iframe.

In the iframe I load a textfile.

How can I read the text displayed in the iframe with javascript on my main page?

Here I load the Iframe with the textfile

> document.getElementById("iframe").src=textfile;

Here I want to retrieve the text displayed in the iframe:

> document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML

I tried it with `.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML` or `.contentWindow.document.body.innerText` but that didn't work.

Anybody has an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.getElementById(id).contentDocument.body.innerText` to get it

but you can also fetch it directly from the url parsed to your iframe src